# Tableau to create single chart from multiple parameters

Tags: charts, parameters, filter, tableau-api

I have [tableau workbook online](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/Finance_151/Infl-AdjustedTrend2)

Before, I had filter for **single Principal**, and applied to all CUSIPs, and I was able to plot all the inflation-adjusted principals based on Index ratios for a particular date, (refer tab `Inflation-Adjusted Trend`) i.e.

[image]

Now, I have multiple filters based on multiple Principals, i.e. buy one CUSIP for $1500, buy another for $900, etc (refer tab `Infl-Adjusted Trend 2`)

[image]

These were the columns and rows

[image]

But I do not like the format of this graph.

I wish to have all the lines together in one graph, just like the single-principal tab below ..... how to fix this? How to bring all the values into one chart?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have six calculated fields calculating your inflation-adjusted principals, one for each CUSIP. Here's what that table might end up looking like:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| CUSIP     | 912828H45 P | 912828NM8 P | 912828PP9 P | 912828QV5 P | ... |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| 912828H45 | $100        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | ... |
| 912828NM8 | NULL        | $455        | NULL        | NULL        | ... |
| 912828PP9 | NULL        | NULL        | $132        | NULL        | ... |
| 912828QV5 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | $553        | ... |
| ...       | ...         | ...         | ...         | ...         | ... |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----|
```

There's definitely a better way. Your fields are set up like this:

```
IF [Cusip] = "912828H45"
THEN
[912828H45 Principal] * [Index Ratio] 
END
```

Instead of setting up one field per CUSIP, make a single field that calculates that value for each CUSIP.

```
IF [Cusip] = "912828H45"
THEN
[912828H45 Principal] * [Index Ratio] 
ELSEIF [Cusip] = "912828NM8"
THEN
[912828NM8 Principal] * [Index Ratio]
...
END
```

Now your table looks like this.

```
+-----------+------------------------------+-----+
| CUSIP     | Inflation-Adjusted Principal | ... |
+-----------+------------------------------+-----+
| 912828H45 | $100                         | ... |
| 912828NM8 | $455                         | ... |
| 912828PP9 | $132                         | ... |
| 912828QV5 | $553                         | ... |
| ...       | ...                          | ... |
+-----------+------------------------------+-----+
```

That's a LOT easier to work with. Drag that single field into Rows and color by [Cusip].